# How to solve an error in Heroku's config/database.yml file "mapping values are not allowed in this context"

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra, psych, heroku-postgres

I'm deploying an app to Heroku and it's mostly fine but for this error

```
mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 22 column 13 (Psych::SyntaxError)
```

The line they are referring to is line 22 of the database.yml file that Heroku itself is writing over my own file, as per standard practice.

Jumping into `heroku run bash` and taking a look at the file in question:

```
<%

require 'cgi'
require 'uri'

begin
  uri = URI.parse(ENV["DATABASE_URL"])
rescue URI::InvalidURIError
  raise "Invalid DATABASE_URL"
end

raise "No RACK_ENV or RAILS_ENV found" unless ENV["RAILS_ENV"] || ENV["RACK_ENV"]

def attribute(name, value, force_string = false)
  if value
    value_string =
      if force_string
        '"' + value + '"'
      else
        value
      end
    "#{name}: #{value_string}"
  else
    ""
  end
end

adapter = uri.scheme
adapter = "postgresql" if adapter == "postgres"

database = (uri.path || "").split("/")[1]

username = uri.user
password = uri.password

host = uri.host
port = uri.port

params = CGI.parse(uri.query || "")

%>

<%= ENV["RAILS_ENV"] || ENV["RACK_ENV"] %>:
  <%= attribute "adapter",  adapter %>
  <%= attribute "database", database %>
  <%= attribute "username", username %>
  <%= attribute "password", password, true %>
  <%= attribute "host",     host %>
  <%= attribute "port",     port %>

<% params.each do |key, value| %>
  <%= key %>: <%= value.first %>
<% end %>
```

Line 22 is

```
    "#{name}: #{value_string}"
```

Any suggestions as to how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Okay after some more research I have worked out the problem.  Sigh.

On my local machine I am loading my database configuration as follows:

```
dbconfig = YAML::load(File.open(File.join("config","database.yml")))
```

but because the `yml` file that Heroku generates is actually an `ERB` file in disguise, I need to parse it first.

Changing the above line to:

```
dbconfig = YAML.load(ERB.new(File.read(File.join("config","database.yml"))).result)
```

works a treat.

Comment: Heroku assumes the file is for Rails, and Rails filters it through ERB first the same way as you do here: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-0-stable/railties/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb#L106

Comment: Which is odd as my app is a vanilla Rack app that uses a bunch of Sinatra components.

Comment: don't forget to require 'erb' in your Rakefile